# jquery ' Uncaught ReferenceError not defined' error message in chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some error msg in chrome console and the expected result does not show up  . can't make out
what code segment produces it. SO FINDING NO OTHER WAY, I JUST PASTED THE CODE HERE

Console says :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: meraj_63193201111201321808488_white is not defined

and the line number it gives is 95.

But at line number 95, I have:

> alert("success value ="+arg2);

**WHAT I WANT TO DO** :

using `jquery-ui` , i used a dialog box for IMAGE FILE uploading. After the file gets uploaded I want to show a preview of it in photo_upload_preview_indiv class.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Upload Your Profile Picture">
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" onsubmit="startUpload();"                             style="border1111111:1px solid yellow; margin-top:0px">
        <p id="f1_upload_form" align="center"><!--<br/>-->
            <label>
                <br>File:  
                <input name="myfile" type="file" size="30" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p id="f1_upload_process">Loading...<br/><img src="img/loader.gif" /><!--<br/>--></p>
        <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
    </form>

    <div class="photo_upload_previews">
        <div class="photo_upload_preview_indiv"></div><!-- end of class photo_upload_preview_indiv-->
    </div><!--end of class photo_upload_previews -->
</div><!-- end of id dialog -->
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dialog = $('#dialog');

        dialog.dialog({
            width:860,
            height:560,
            autoOpen: false
        });

        //dialog.dialog( "option", "10", 'top' );

        $(".upload_photos").bind('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#f1_upload_process").css('display','none');
            dialog.dialog('open');
        });
    });;//]]>  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startUpload(){
        $("#f1_upload_process").css('display','block');

        document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        //$(".prof_pic_up_instruct_text").css('display','none');
        return true;
    }

    function stopUpload(success, arg2){
        var result = '';

        alert("success value ="+arg2);

        if (success == 1) {
            alert('file name ='+<?php echo $_SESSION['uploaded_file_name']; ?>);

            $("#f1_upload_process").css('display','none');

            document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'visible';

            //$("#dialog").dialog('close');

            $(".prof_pic_up_instruct_text").hide();
            $("#f1_upload_process").hide();

            //$(".photo_upload_preview_indiv:last").append('<div class="photo_upload_preview_indiv"><img src="src/"+arg2/></div>');

            alert("0000000000000000");
        }
        else {
            result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!<\/span><br/><br/>';
        }
        document.getElementById('f1_upload_process').style.visibility = 'hidden';

        //document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').innerHTML = result + '<label>File: <input name="myfile" type="file" size="30" /><\/label><label><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="sbtn" value="Upload" /><\/label>';

        document.getElementById('f1_upload_form').style.visibility = 'visible';      
        return true;   
    }
</script>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Edit upload location here
    $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $result = 0;

    $target_path = $destination_path .'uploads/'.basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);

    if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        $result = 1;
    }

    sleep(1);
    $_SESSION['uploaded_file_name']=$_FILES['myfile']['name'].$_FILES["file"]["type"];
    $uploaded_file_name=$_SESSION['uploaded_file_name'];
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.top.window.stopUpload('<?php echo $result; ?>' , '<?php echo $uploaded_file_name;  ?>');
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

meraj_63193201111201321808488_white.jpg was the file I tried to upload.

Answer (score 0):

This is not line 95 of your JS, but line 95 of the HTML generated by the page which contains inline JS. The name of the uploaded file appears to be quoted improperly. I do see quotes around the output you currently have, but I would double-check what output gets sent to the browser.

Comment: i am also talking about my html page. Will be waiting with much eagerness to hear from you

Comment: Can you post exactly what gets output to the browser from your PHP script?

Comment: I tried to upload shopnotori_simon.jpg and got this : Uncaught ReferenceError: shopnotori_simon is not defined index_photo.php:95.

Comment: Can you post exactly what gets output to the browser from your PHP script?

Comment: it shows Loading... along with the image loader.gif. nothing shows up on the browser

Comment: i did in my question . notice please

Comment: I haven't tried setting up and running your script. Posting the HTML output would help people provide solutions.

Comment: I said what the output was:  
it shows Loading... along with the image loader.gif. nothing else shows up on the browser.. How can I know when u will be online to have a chat with u?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed That is not HTML. That is just a description of what is being displayed. Please look at the source of the page and post the output if possible. I will post a comment if I am available to chat this evening.

Comment: please make it a bit clearer to me. source of which page? output page?

Comment: u gave an url to know about window.top . that part was transferred to chat ... and i dont knoe wheteher I can view the chat conversation yet. so the link again please? and , is there any way to view chat records/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6427/discussion-between-michael-mior-and-istiaque-ahmed)

Comment: sorry, i posted last 2 comments here mistakenly. those were supposed to be for my another post